# Create a rxjs pipe that combines values based on their type before processing them asynchronously in concatMap

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have an `eventStream` that accepts events of various types and processes them (sends them to server via HTTP).

```
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

type Update = number[];

interface Event {
  type: 'add' | 'delete' | 'update';
  data: Update;
}

const eventStream = from([
  { type: 'update', data: [1] },
  { type: 'update', data: [2] },
  { type: 'add', data: [3] },
  { type: 'update', data: [4] },
  { type: 'update', data: [5] },
  { type: 'delete', data: [6] },
  { type: 'update', data: [7] },
  // ... other events
]);

function postEvent(event: Event): Observable<any> {
  // ... post event to server
}

eventStream.pipe(concatMap(event => postEvent(event)))
```

How do I modify the pipe so that a sequence of **consecutive** unproccessed `update` events are combined into one using `combineUpdates` function to save some HTTP requests, while keeping the order of the events?

```
/*
Combines multiple consecutive update events into a single update event:
 { type: 'update', data: [1] }, { type: 'update', data: [2] }, => { type: 'update', data: [1, 2] }
*/
function combineUpdates(updates: Event[]): Event {
  return { type: 'update', data: updates.map(e => e.data).flat()};
}
```

E.g.:
`eventStream` above should transform to following `postEvent()` calls:

```
  { type: 'update', data: [1, 2] },
  { type: 'add', data: [3] },
  { type: 'update', data: [4, 5] },
  { type: 'delete', data: [6] },
  { type: 'update', data: [7] },
```

Comment: Could you please expand upon the usage of the word "unproccessed" here? What does it exactly mean? Does it mean that the HTTP request for that event isn't complete yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `concatMap` and pushing the data to an array, please find below a working example!

```
import { from, Observable, of, switchMap } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

type Update = number[];

interface Event {
  type: 'add' | 'delete' | 'update';
  data: Update;
}

const eventStream = from(<Array<Event>>[
  { type: 'update', data: [1] },
  { type: 'update', data: [2] },
  { type: 'add', data: [3] },
  { type: 'add', data: [3] },
  { type: 'update', data: [4] },
  { type: 'update', data: [5] },
  { type: 'delete', data: [6] },
  { type: 'update', data: [7] },
  // ... other events
]);

function postEvent(event: Event): Observable<any> {
  console.log('post data', event);
  return of(true);
}

function combineUpdates(updates: Event[]): Event {
  return { type: 'update', data: updates.map((e) => e.data).flat() };
}

let updateArray: Array<Event> = [];
const streamLogic$ = eventStream.pipe(
  concatMap((event: Event): any => {
    debugger;
    if (event.type === 'update') {
      updateArray.push(event);
      return of(null);
    } else {
      if (updateArray.length) {
        const apiArray = [];
        if (updateArray?.length) {
          const data = combineUpdates(updateArray);
          updateArray = [];
          apiArray.push(postEvent(data));
        }
        apiArray.push(postEvent(event));
        return from(apiArray);
      } else {
        return postEvent(event);
      }
    }
  })
);

streamLogic$.subscribe({
  complete: () => {
    if (updateArray.length) {
      const data = combineUpdates(updateArray);
      updateArray = [];
      postEvent(data).subscribe();
    }
  },
});

// { type: 'update', data: [1, 2] },
//   { type: 'add', data: [3] },
//   { type: 'update', data: [4, 5] },
//   { type: 'delete', data: [6] },
//   { type: 'update', data: [7] },
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vrzji5?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I forgot to stress that the order of postEvent() calls need to keep order of the events. I added the information and also an example of expected output.

Comment: Thank you! I believe there is an issue in your else-else branch.
If I change `return switchMap(postEvent);` to `return postEvent(event);` it seems to work correctly.

Try adding another non-update event after `{ type: 'add', data: [3] },` to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would proceed defining a custom operator that transforms a sequence of updates into one single update operation and leaves the other operations untouched.

The code of the custom operator could be the following

```
// combineUpdates is a function that returns a custom operator
// a custom operator is a function that takes an Observable as input and
// returns an Observable
function combineUpdates() {
  return (source: Observable<Event>) => {
    // the custom operator needs some state to store:
    // - a flag that signals that we are in an 'update' sequence
    // - the values received in the 'update' sequence
    let isUpdate = false;
    let updateArray: number[] = [];
    // the Observable returned transforms the values received from the source and
    // passes them downstream to the subscriber after the transformation
    return new Observable((subscriber: Subscriber<Event>) => {
      const subscription = source.subscribe({
        next: (value) => {
          // if we encounter an update we store the value in the array and pass nothing downstream
          isUpdate = value.type === 'update';
          if (isUpdate) {
            updateArray.push(...value.data);
            return;
          }
          // if it is not an update and if there are values in the update array we pass an 'update' event with the values stored in the array
          if (updateArray.length > 0) {
            subscriber.next({ type: 'update', data: updateArray });
          }
          // we then reset the update array
          updateArray = [];
          // and then we pass the not-'update' event downstream
          subscriber.next(value);
        },
        error: (err) => subscriber.error(err),
        complete: () => subscriber.complete(),
      });
      return () => {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      };
    });
  }
}
```

Then, once we have the custom operator, we can use it like this (similarly to how we use other operators, e.g. `toArray`)

```
const streamLogic$ = eventStream.pipe(
  combineUpdates()
);

streamLogic$.subscribe({
  next: console.log,
});
```

Here a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-zyweee?file=index.ts).

In [this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/an-interesting-case-for-using-a-custom-rxjs-operator-da8443a89c3a) you can find a more detailed description of what custom operators are.